# json dependency added in pom.xml get error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, ujmp

I am working with Sparse Matrix in my project. To build a Sparse Matrix I am using Universal Java Matrix Package. I add all the dependency in my pom.xml file.My pom.xml file is like that.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
<artifactId>ujmp-core</artifactId>
<version>0.3.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-gui</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-commonsmath</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-complete</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-ejml</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-examples</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-itext</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jackcess</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jama</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jblas</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jmatio</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jsci</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jscience</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-jung</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-la4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-lucene</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-mail</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-mtj</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-ojalgo</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-parallelcolt</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-poi</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-vecmath</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I added this dependency on my own. All the dependency in added from ujmp.org website from there documentation. After added all the dependency one error is still there `Error:(30, 16) java: package org.json does not exist.Error:(75, 40) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONTokener
  location: class org.ujmp.core.util.JsonUtil. Error:(72, 38) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JSONTokener
  location: class org.ujmp.core.util.JsonUtil`

So I think added json dependency in my pom.xml file should remove the error.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ujmp-json</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But error not removed and the version 0.3.0 is not recognized. It show in a red sign. So what should I do? I am using Intellij Idea. There is no dependency added for json in the UJMP official website. Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: `ujmp-core` core is not declared as a dependency, it is declared as if your project itself was `ujmp-core` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove:

```
<groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
<artifactId>ujmp-core</artifactId>
<version>0.3.0</version>
```

add in dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ujmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>ujmp-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```